# Unable to create subnet in VPC - getting "Not with in Range error"

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, subnet

I have VPC with subnet 172.16.0.0/28 in AWS.

I am getting error while creating 2nd Subnet for our NAT instance.

Eg, Getting Error if i try this subnet "172.16.0.0/24 is not within the range of 172.16.0.0/28"

and getting this error if  i try "CIDR block 172.16.0.6/28 overlaps with pre-existing CIDR block 172.16.0.0/28"

Isn't possible to create subnet for this /28 range. I am not as good in Subnetting- Network.

Comment: What it the CIDR for your VPC?

Comment: VPC CIDR is 172.16.0.0/28

Answer (score 4):

`/24` subnet is larger than `/28` so it certainly is not within the range.

If you are not familiar with subnetting, I suggest you stick with `/16` VPC CIDR  and `/24` subnets.

For example, create a VPC with CIDR block `172.16.0.0/16`, and than add your subnets like:

```
subnet0 CIDR: 172.16.0.0/24
subnet1 CIDR: 172.16.1.0/24
subnet2 CIDR: 172.16.2.0/24
...
```

Or just "Contact your system administrator" :)